# SOlR and keywords

Tags: solr, keyword, cat

I have this script:

```
$removeList = array('+', '-', '&&', '||', '!', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '^', '"', '~', '*', '?', ':', '\\');
$keyword = str_replace($removeList, '', mb_strtolower($_GET['query'], 'UTF-8'));
$keyword_str = strlen($keyword);    

if($keyword_str>=3){
    $options = array('hostname' => '**.*.*.*','login' => '', 'password' => '', 'port' => 8080);
    $client = new SolrClient($options);
    $query = new SolrQuery();
    $query->setTerms(true);
    $query->setTermsLimit(10);
    $query->setTermsSort(1);
    $query->setTermsField('keywords')->setTermsPrefix($keyword);
    $updateResponse = $client->query($query);
}
```

This script is working fine. But how can I make it search by category?

Example: my var are `$_GET['query'] = 'au'` but i want to search only in cat = 2. Now its searching the whole DB. how can I make that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the TermsComponent? If not, my suggestion would be to build your query by using `SolrQuery::setQuery` and setting a static filter on the cat field by the help of Solr's [Query Syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax).

Example:

```
<?php

    /* ... */

    $query = new SolrQuery();
    $query->setQuery('(cat:2) AND (keywords:' . $keyword . ')');

    /* ... */

?>
```

... or in short form using `SolrQuery` constructor:

```
<?php

    /* ... */

    $query = new SolrQuery('(cat:2) AND (keywords:' . $keyword . ')');

    /* ... */

?>
```